# Selecting exactly one element along the specified dimension in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing

I have 2 tensors, namely `X of shape (?, 32, 500)` and `indices of shape (?,)`. For both tensors, the 0th dimension is a batch dimension. Each element of `indices` specifies the index of `X` along the 1st dimension to select. In the end, I'd like to get a tensor of shape `(?, 500)`. In numpy I would do it this way:

```
X[np.arange(len(X)), indices]
```

Does anyone know how to achieve the same in tensorflow (version 1)? I already looked at some examples of `tf.gather` and `tf.gather_nd`, but couldn't get my head around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tf.range`, `tf.stack` and `tf.gather_nd`:

```py
def fancy_index_arange(X, indices):
    arange = tf.range(len(X))
    fancy_index = tf.stack([arange, indices], axis=1)
    result = tf.gather_nd(X, fancy_index)
    return result
```

verify shape:

```py
>>> X = tf.random.normal((10, 32, 500))
>>> indices = tf.random.uniform((10,), minval=0, maxval=32, dtype=tf.int32)

>>> fancy_index_arange(X, indices).shape
TensorShape([10, 500])
```

tested with `tf.__version__ == "2.3.0"`